# Best way to do this kind of drop shadow?

Tags: css, drop-shadow

I have a site that will have a column of images and divs (a mix of both) that will always be the same size.

On all of these I want to add a certain kind of drop shadow (as seen here):
[image]

I've worked with CSS drop shadows but I've never seen one like this in CSS.  Can this be done in CSS?  Assuming it cannot then I'm guessing I would use just a drop shadow slice as a graphic, possibly a background.  If that is the only route to go, how do I apply this to every image or div?

Right now what I'm doing is putting a div under each image or div:

```
<div class="rightimgdropshadow">&nbsp;</div>
```

...and doing this in CSS:
.rightimgdropshadow

```
{
    background-image: url(../images/site-structure/right-col-image-shadow.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    width 100%
    height: 20px;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: You need to use CSS3 Transforms to achieve that type of shadow, but its messy and poorly supported!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you prefere to use CSS to create that type of shadows, you can use CSS3 as [seen here!](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/)

**CSS**

```
/* Lifted corners */

.lifted {
    -moz-border-radius:4px; 
         border-radius:4px;
}

.lifted:before,
.lifted:after { 
    bottom:15px;
    left:10px;
    width:50%;
    height:20%;
    max-width:300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);   
       -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);    
       -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);   
        -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);   
         -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
            transform:rotate(-3deg);
}

.lifted:after {
    right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);   
       -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);  
        -ms-transform:rotate(3deg);  
         -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
            transform:rotate(3deg);
}
```

[Made a Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/mPnTP/)

Comment: Woah, excellent...I did NOT know you could do those with CSS!  Much more elegant than my solution...thanks (and thanks for the link to it as well!)

Comment: CSS3 Really came to rock the web :)

Comment: Don't you hate it when you submit a simple answer and as you submit the page reloads with something as good as this ;) sweet link too mate, +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-shadow`:

```
.rightimgdropshadow { 
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

This will create a similar effect, but it won't look just the same.

[Some info](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/) on that.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
border: 1px solid #333;
border-bottom: none;
padding: 10px 10px 20px;
background: url('insert_image') no-repeat;
background-position: left bottom;
```

The extra padding at the bottom allows the background to sit in the correct place.

Does that help?